# How to republish Hosted Feature Layers on ArcGIS Online without losing the data?

Tags: arcgis-online, publishing, hosting

I am desgning an App on ArcGIS Online for deploying tactical plans over the terrain. My workflow is next:

1. Design dataset and feature layers using ArcMap 10.2, using our Enterprise Geodatabase (Oracle)
2. Create a Map whith layers and simbology in ArcMap 10.2
3. Publish this map as a hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online, using our enterprise account. The service is configured as Feautre Layer service, to allow editing to AGOL user
4. Go to ArcGIS Online and author a Map with this hosted feautre layer and an App with WebApp Builder
5. User can now start to work with the app, in a testing phase. User are now generating testing plans, and identifing new requirments a functionality needed

This new requirments, are some like, add new layers, or new fields to the existing layers, or new subtypes....

So with this needs, we continue developing this App, using this workflow:

1. Edit the Layers and Maps with ArcMap to incorporate new requirments, updating our local entreprise Geodatabase
2. Publish the service again, modifing the existing one. (Modify option of the publishing process)

The problem we have is that with this workflow we are losing all the data generated in ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Layers. So the question is: What is the correct workflow we must follow to assure that AGOL Hosted Feature layers data generated by users is not lost?

Comment: You can export data from the service and make changes to that dataset and overwrite the existing hosted layer. Note that if you are adding layers to the Hosted Layer you will need to update your web map b/c the web map is only referencing the layer originally added in the spec.

Comment: You should check out this new Append workflow https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E2F5EF6240F246EBA5D238968B63BF97

Comment: thx Russ, very useful information. So I underestand my workflow must be the next: 1-Prior to republish, export data to GDB with Arcmap. 2-Republish service with the modify option. 3-Use update data option of the Hosted layer in Arcgis Online to reload the data.

Comment: Yup, try that out and see if that supports your workflow case. Let us know if you have any feedback.